# Quarkus Arc: Unsatisfied dependency for PanacheRepository in CDI service - jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm encountering an issue while working with Quarkus and Panache where I receive the following error during the application startup:

```
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 2 deployment problems: 
[1] Unsatisfied dependency for type br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.repository.DisciplineRepository and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.service.DisciplineService():disciplineRepository
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.service.DisciplineService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.service.DisciplineService]
[2] Unsatisfied dependency for type br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.repository.StudentRepository and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.service.StudentService():studentRepository
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.service.StudentService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=br.com.pongolino.study.quarkus.service.StudentService]
...
```

The project is very simple, its just two repositories extending from PanacheRepository<> and a service that is called in a resource.

The issue seems to be related to unsatisfied dependencies for PanacheRepository interfaces in CDI services (`DisciplineService` and `StudentService`).

- The PanacheRepository interfaces (`DisciplineRepository` and `StudentRepository`) are annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`.
- CDI services (`DisciplineService` and `StudentService`) are injecting these repositories, leading to the reported deployment problems.

```
// DisciplineRepository
@ApplicationScoped
public interface DisciplineRepository extends PanacheRepository<Discipline> {
}

// DisciplineService
@ApplicationScoped
public class DisciplineService {
    @Inject
    DisciplineRepository disciplineRepository;
    // ...
}

// StudentRepository
@ApplicationScoped
public interface StudentRepository extends PanacheRepository<Student> {
}

// StudentService
@ApplicationScoped
public class StudentService {
    @Inject
    StudentRepository studentRepository;
    // ...
}

// Resource (Simplified)
@Path("/v1/discipline")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DisciplineResource {
    private final DisciplineService disciplineService;

    @Inject
    public DisciplineResource(DisciplineService disciplineService) {
        this.disciplineService = disciplineService;
    }

   // ...
}
```

**POM**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**Attempts**

1. I have removed the quarkus-jdbc-mysql dependency and configured the datasource explicitly. But it seems to not be related to the problem. (I removed because the quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache already have the necessaries tools to run mysql independently?!)
2. I have tried to re-generate the project structure and move the class to the new one.
3. I have the feeling that there is a dependency missing; Maybe?

**Questions:**

1. What could be causing these unsatisfied dependencies, especially after removing `quarkus-jdbc-mysql`?
2. Are there additional configurations OR **DEPENDENCIES** needed for PanacheRepository interfaces in Quarkus?

Comment: Does it work if you change your interfaces to classes that implement `PanacheRepository` instead of extending it? That's what https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache shows.

Comment: @RobSpoor Yes, you are right. I thought it was the same way as when we do it with Spring Data for creating Repositories. Thank you.

Comment: @RobSpoor your comment sounds like an answer :)

Comment: @geoand I wasn't too sure at first, hence the question. Now that it is confirmed to solve the issue I've posted it as an answer, that's better visible for future readers than some comment.

Answer (score 1):

Change your interfaces to classes that implement PanacheRepository instead of extending it. That's what quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache shows.